# Synchronize facebook comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

We are using facebook comments on a simple client blog. I am wondering if or how comments on a particular url, can also display as on the post when it is shared on facebook. Is it supposed to work this way? For example, a user posts a comment on a blog posts (via the blog), the post url has also so been posted on a facebook page, can the fb comments be synced up somehow?